# Panda Dataframe - Using .iterrows() is there a better way?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am using df.iterrows() for the following task.

Col3 in the below table is based on the values in col1 & col2.

```
+------+------+-------+
| col1 | col2 | col3  |
+------+------+-------+
|    1 | A    | White |
|    1 | B    | Green |
|    2 | A    | Blue  |
|    2 | B    | Red   |
+------+------+-------+
```

This is the code I am using, it takes a while as the DataFrame has many rows.

```
for i, r in df.iterrows():
    if r.col1 == "1" and r.col2 == "A":
        value = "White"
    elif r.col1 == "1" and r.col2 != "B":
        value = "Green"
    elif r.col1 == "2" and r.col2 == "A":
        value = "Blue"
    elif r.col1 == "2" and r.col2 != "B":
        value = "Red"
    else:
        value = None

    df.loc[i, 'col3'] = value
```

I am convinced there must be a better way but my searches haven't been successful so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best in my opinion is to use a dictionary to map the values, then [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
d = {(1, 'A'): 'White', (1, 'B'): 'Green', (2, 'A'): 'Blue', (2, 'B'): 'Red'}

out = df.merge(pd.Series(d, name='col3'), left_on=['col1', 'col2'],
               right_index=True, how='left')
```

if the col3 column is already existing:

```
df['col3'] = df.merge(pd.Series(d, name='col3'), left_on=['col1', 'col2'],
                      right_index=True, suffixes=('_', None))['col3']
```

output:

```
   col1 col2   col3
0     1    A  White
1     1    B  Green
2     2    A   Blue
3     2    B    Red
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `numpy.select`:

```
import numpy as np

conditions = [df["col1"].eq(1)&df["col2"].eq("A"),
              df["col1"].eq(1)&df["col2"].eq("B"),
              df["col1"].eq(2)&df["col2"].eq("A"),
              df["col1"].eq(2)&df["col2"].eq("B")]

choices = ["White", "Green", "Blue", "Red"]

df["col3"] = np.select(conditions, choices, None)
```

Comment: the drawback here is the scalability, it gets difficult to type all the conditions when the number increases (well you can use a loop), but you also perform many comparisons uselessly ;)

Answer (score 0):

A probably less performing solution would be to create an aggregation column and use map to translate it:

```
df['col3'] = (df.col1.astype(str)+df.col2).map({'1A':"White", '1B':"Green", '2A':"Blue", '2B':"Red"})
```